# How to test win Selenium 2 if site is active at all then test if basic http authentication is present or failed?

Tags: selenium, basic-authentication

I first need to know if the site is present at all, such as when the connection is refused rather than a browser error or something, then test basic http authentication is present or failed, ie to know that the failure is due to the presence of http authentication.

I first want to find out if a failure is due to http authentication, then if it is try with a password and find out if that also fails or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RoadMap

> Support HTTP Basic and Digest Authentication:     Not Started

So just wait for it.

If a site is present you can check by testing if a specific element you expect to appear is present or not. Therefore you need a timeout (maybe 30 sec.) after which you can mark the test as a fail if the element didn't appear in that time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add - only way to go to HTTP Basic authentification site is via loading URL like:

```
http://username:password@the-site.com
```

I suggest having test which loads page via this URL - then you know that HTTP basic auth is there

Its kinda workaround solution, but there is nothing better yet

Comment: this won't work with internet explorer due to security reasons. i am just adding this information for your interest.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the comment. I am using the Chrome and here it works fine